# C++ error only when compiled with no optimizations (GCC)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc

Here is some code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class ShowHello {
 public:
    string operator()(int x) {return "hello";}
};

template<typename F>
class A {
 private:
    static F f;
    static inline string foo(const int& x) {
        return f(x);
    }

 public:
    A() {
        cout << "foo: " << foo(10) << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<ShowHello> a;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is me compiling it with some optimizations:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O1 -Wall test.cc -o test && ./test
foo: hello
```

And no optimizations

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall test.cc -o test && ./test
/tmp/ccXdtXVe.o: In function `A<ShowHello>::foo(int const&)':
test.cc:(.text._ZN1AI9ShowHelloE3fooERKi[_ZN1AI9ShowHelloE3fooERKi]+0x2a): undefined reference to `A<ShowHello>::f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: You *declare* the static member variable `f`, but you never *define* it. In the optimized build, it's probably optimized out since it's not used.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *declare* a static member variable `f` here:

```
static F f;
```

and then you [odr-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) it here:

```
static inline string foo(const int& x) {
    return f(x);
}
```

That requires a definition of `f` be available, but you haven't provided a definition - just the declaration. That makes the program ill-formed, no diagnostic required. However, in practice, a definition is only necessary if the linker actually needs it - and in this case, the optimized build simply inlined the call completely, without even bothering with either the static member or your class. Indeed, the instructions include fun things like:

```
    movl    $1819043176, 16(%rsp)  // this is "hell"
    movl    $5, %edx
    movl    std::cout, %edi
    movq    $5, 8(%rsp)
    movb    $111, 4(%rsi)          // this is 'o'
```

Cool stuff.

Anyway, the unoptimized build does actually rely upon having a definition of `f` because the call is actually made - and you don't have a definition, hence the linker error. The optimized build doesn't rely on `f`, but you should define it anyway, for correctness.

```
template <typename F>
struct A { ... };

template <typename F>
F A<F>::f;
```

Comment: In C++17, you’ll be able to skip the separate definition step, and instead both declare and define it inside the class with `inline static F f;`. If a static member variable is `constexpr` it is also automatically `inline`, which is nice.